# CreateProcess() параметры командной строки

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании нового процесса, с помощью `CreateProcess()`, в него передать `char* argv[]`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод CreateProcessA(). Он вместо LPCSTR принимает ASCII строку.

Comment: Подскажите, чем LPCSTR отличается от указателя на Си-строку? И заодно поправьте орфографию "принЕмает".

Comment: Очепятнулся: в параметрах CreateProcess фигурирует LPCTSTR, который расшифровывается так:
LP — Long Pointer (Длинный указатель)
C — Constant (Константа)
T = TCHAR
STR = String (Строка)